# Adding onserverclick event to a HtmlAnchor dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling, anchor

I've got a page and would like to append the onserverclick event to my existing
HtmlAnchor.

In the design view I am first adding the control

```
<a runat="server" id="lnkFre" title="FR" onclick="document.getElementById('ctl00_hidLang').value='en-US';"><span>Français</span> </a>
```

I tried like this.

```
HtmlAnchor lnkFre = FindControl("lnkFre") as HtmlAnchor;
lnkFre.ServerClick += new EventHandler(lnkLang_Click);
```

Here the lnkLang_Click is an event in a class which is accessible from this page.

But at runtime it is not being added.

I wish to have something like this.

```
<a runat="server" id="lnkFre" title="FR" onserverclick="lnkLang_Click" onclick="document.getElementById('ctl00_hidLang').value='fr-BE';"><span>Français</span> </a>
```

Is this possible in this way? Or kindly suggest me another method.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#A" runat="server" id="MyAnchor" onclick="alert('test');return true;">A</a>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HtmlAnchor lnkFre = MyAnchor as HtmlAnchor;
     lnkFre.ServerClick += new EventHandler(lnkFre_ServerClick);
}

void lnkFre_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You obviously won't be able to see the markup at runtime as the event is being bound dynamically but it will call the server click event.

Please also note the `return(true);` at the end of the onclick event. This is necessary for the server click to also fire.