# onServerClick function not working on Dynamic Creation

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have several anchor buttons with onServerClick methods being dynamically created, but when I click on the buttons on the webpage, they will not call the function. Below is an example of a tag:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="button0" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onserverclick="reportMessage" creator="Tom" content="This is a test."><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Report</a>
```

And here is some of the method that is being called:

```
private void reportMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (HtmlAnchor)sender;
        string content = btn.Attributes["content"].ToString();
        string commentCreator = btn.Attributes["creator"].ToString()}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly you need something like this: `btn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(reportMessage)` on `Page_Load` event before you can get those attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

Since `button0` is HTML anchor control ID, you can add a handler to `ServerClick` event in `Page_Load` event to handle each anchor link like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAnchor btn = button0 as HtmlAnchor;
    btn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(reportMessage);
}
```

Additionally you can add `onclick` event contains `return true` to ensure server click event is firing.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="button0" onserverclick="reportMessage" onclick="return true;" ...>Link Text</a>
```

NB: Since `reportMessage` is an event handler method bound to `HtmlAnchor`, I recommend using `protected` level instead of `private`.

Similar issue:

[Adding onserverclick event to a HtmlAnchor dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744126/adding-onserverclick-event-to-a-htmlanchor-dynamically)

Comment: This makes sense, but since I am creating these anchor tags dynamically including their ids, I can't call these methods in the Page-Load because they do not yet exist nor do I know the amount of anchor tags being created. Any suggestions on making this happen?